First choice for President polls? (As opposed to who you plan to vote for polls.)
Have there been any polls during this presidential election season asking which candidate is the person's first choice?  (If so, details?)
I ask because, as widely reported (e.g. copy here), it's believed that, based on exit polls, if voters had voted for the candidate they preferred win the presidency in 1992, Ross Perot would surely have won easily: Perot would have received about 40% of the popular vote per exit poll analysis by above source - though I don't see a per-state/electoral college analysis.
Research:
I'm looking on https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/president-general/2024/national/ and I can't find any.
I have read many articles about polls this season and haven't heard of any such results.
(The closest thing I'm aware of are favorability ratings.

Donald J Trump 9.4% more unfavorable☨ and stable.
Robert F Kennedy 5.9% more unfavorable☨, about a 25 % drop from early in the campaign.
Kamala Harris trending rapidly toward neutral, started mostly favorable, but has been ~15% more unfavorable☨ for most of the campaign.
ABC/538 chooses not to report favorability ratings on other presidential candidates.

But I'm not aware of any efforts to correlate such results to first choice polling questions.  (Anyone aware of technical work on this? - reason for polling tag.) )
☨ "X% more unfavorable" means  "X% more unfavorable than favorable."
See https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/favorability/ for more sources and explanations.

Wilson indeed won with a 'landslide' (electoral college wise) the 1912 election with only around 42% of the popular vote, in a 3/4-way race. But I'm more skeptical of that single poll that the Perrot claim is based on.

So the claim of that 1992 poll is that people really liked that one candidate but thought he wouldn't have a chance anyway and voted tactically for someone else, validating their fears. If only they would have been more brave they could have had what they really wanted. Or it's maybe but true and they liked the alternatives more.

Possible bias. Can you use either 'Trump/Kennedy/Harris' or 'Donald/Robert/Kamala'. Mixing given names with surnames is strange. Yes, I'm aware that using Robert for RFK Jr. is unusual but the "Donald" is not at all strange.

changed to full names. Did you down vote because of this possible bias?

Not sure why you felt the need to put in the middle initial for two of the candidates but felt like leaving it out for the third. Wouldn't it be better to just leave it out for all of them instead of appearing to continue to make a statement like you did when you used the last name of two of them and the first name of the third?

please add it. I don’t know what it is. was not making a statement.  FS.

I think you misunderstood, I was suggesting to remove it from the other two instead of adding to to the third. I don't know what her middle initial is either, rather I am just pointing out how using it for two but not the third looks after you changed it from two last names and one first name to this.

@JoeW - Eh, I'm fine with this version of it (I agree about the possibly-unconscious bias in the previous form).  Trump and his supporters do refer to him with the J, and RFK is obviously including the F.  If Harris isn't using her middle initial, then there's no reason to add it just because the others have it, or remove the others because she doesn't.

I am not clear what you mean by saying " more unfavorable". Compared to what? The favorable view at that time? The favorable or neutral view at that time? Compared to the previous poll? The favorable view dropped some percentage?

@JoelHarmon I think it's the comparison between favorable and unfavorable at the time. E.g. 40% favorable vs 45% unfavorable is 5% more unfavorable.

@Barmar I agree that it seems likely that was the intent. The question would be improved if that was more explicit.

" more unfavorable" meaning  " more unfavorable than favorable."  See https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/favorability/ for reference.
That's the language they use there.  It's clear enough for them.
I've added  "X% more unfavorable" means  "X% more unfavorable than favorable."  See https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/favorability/ for more sources and explanations.  Pity no one has an answer!

It's for the primaries, not the actual race, but here's such a poll for the Dems and here's one for Reps.  The organization is specifically focused on promoting ranked-choice voting, and I don't see them even listed on 538's pollster rankings, but it at least shows someone is asking the question.
